# Как приблизить карту в приложении Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

При открытии приложения с картой и метками в моём городе, у меня открывается карта всего мира. Как мне приблизить карту при открытии? Java (использую Android Studio и Google Maps API)

Comment: Нужно добавить код.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы просто изменить зум на любое желаемое значение между минимальным значением = 2,0 и максимальным значением = 21,0:

```
map.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );
```

API предупредит, что не во всех местах плитки имеют значения с максимальным или близким к максимальному масштабированию.

[Здесь](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomBy%28float,%20android.graphics.Point%29) можно почитать более подробно про масштабирование.